# Inifite loop with java.util.Scanner in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, java.util.scanner, infinite-loop

I have to read from console this kind of input:

```
word1
word2

word3
word4
```

I have tried that:

```
public static void lectSC(Scanner sc, String l, boolean next) {
        l=sc.nextLine();     //keep the first line
        while(!l.isEmpty()){ //if it is not empty go! until the white line
            checkDicc(l);//check if is the word that I am looking for
            l=sc.nextLine(); //get the next word
        }
        l=sc.nextLine(); //take the nextLine which has a word3
        while(!l.isEmpty()){
            parejas.add(l);
            next=sc.hasNext(); //HERE IT IS THE INFINITY LOOP
            if(next){ //I try with this next know which is the value of hasNext(), but I never arrive here when it is the last line.
                l=sc.nextLine();
            }else{
                l=""; //It is how it should exit
            }
        }
        System.out.println("OUT");
    }
```

I have to say that when I click from my keyboard Ctrl-Z the program continues but it cannot work like that.

THANKS!!

Answer (score 0):

> The hasNext() method is getting blocked for input

, when reading from Console the program expects a stream and it will wait for further Input.

Below is the official java doc for the method, it does mention it's blocking nature, but not much details about it:-
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext()